# Is there any geometric interpretation or significance of the complex roots of a derivative?

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers, roots

I was doing some reading online when I stumbled [here](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10005.1.shtml) and learned about this geometric way of viewing the complex roots of a function. It got me thinking; the zeros of the derivative of a function $f$ indicate points at which the slope of $f$ is $0$. Is there some kind of geometric interpretation of the complex roots of a function's *derivative*?

Comment: See [Marden's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marden's_theorem), which is a special case of the more general [Gauss-Lucas theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Lucas_theorem). See also [Steiner inellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_inellipse).

Answer (score 0):

The graphical interpretation of complex roots, while cute, only applies to second order polynomials with real coefficients.  And if you have a second order polynomial with real coefficients, its derivative will have no complex roots. SO your question won't elicit any equally cute interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the kind of answer you're looking for, but if $f\colon\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}$ is a complex analytic function, then the zeros of $f'$ are the points where the mapping $f$ is not conformal.